# Error Handler keeps running

Tags: apache-camel

I'm trying to design an Error Handler which performs 3 redelivery attempts and then it stops trying. Here is my camel-context.xml:

```
<errorHandler id="logginghandler" type="DefaultErrorHandler">
  <redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveries="3" redeliveryDelay="5000"
retryAttemptedLogLevel="ERROR" />
</errorHandler>

  <route>
    <from uri="file:/home/user/files/in"/>
    <bean ref="mybean" method="doSomething"/>
    <to uri="jms:queue:myqueue"/>
  </route>
</camelContext>
```

When I execute the Route, however the Handler keeps trying the message redelivery forever:

```
[ile:///home/user/files/in] DefaultErrorHandler            ERROR Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-localhost-localdomain-47568-1462962389320-0-5 on ExchangeId: ID-localhost-localdomain-47568-1462962389320-0-6). On delivery attempt: 2 caught: java.lang.RuntimeException: Errore!
[ile:///home/user/files/in] DefaultErrorHandler            ERROR Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-localhost-localdomain-47568-1462962389320-0-5 on ExchangeId: ID-localhost-localdomain-47568-1462962389320-0-6). On delivery attempt: 3 caught: java.lang.RuntimeException: Errore!
[ile:///home/user/files/in] DefaultErrorHandler            ERROR Failed 
[ile:///home/user/files/in] GenericFileOnCompletion        WARN  Rollback file strategy: org.apache.camel.component.file.strategy.GenericFileRenameProcessStrategy@52f47672 for file: GenericFile[/home/user/files/in/wrong.txt]
[ile:///home/user/files/in] DefaultErrorHandler            ERROR Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-localhost-localdomain-47568-1462962389320-0-5 on ExchangeId: ID-localhost-localdomain-47568-1462962389320-0-6). On delivery attempt: 2 caught: java.lang.RuntimeException: Errore!
[ile:///home/user/files/in] DefaultErrorHandler            ERROR Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-localhost-localdomain-47568-1462962389320-0-5 on ExchangeId: ID-localhost-localdomain-47568-1462962389320-0-6). On delivery attempt: 3 caught: java.lang.RuntimeException: Errore!
```

Any idea what I am missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a file endpoint so the code is rolling back your file and then re-reading the file.  You could try setting: noop=true (If true, the file is not moved or deleted in any way. This option is good for readonly data).  This might resolve your issue.  The other option you might want to set is: moveFailed  This will let you specify an error directory when processing doesn't work as intended.

http://camel.apache.org/file2.html

Comment: Thanks, I've got it!